# Randomly select layer in tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, layer

I want to use different layers with specific probabilities in my network. Layers are the following classes.

```py
class plus1(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def call(self, X):
        return X + 1    
    def compute_output_shape(self, batch_input_shape):
        return batch_input_shape

class plus2(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def call(self, X):
        return X + 2
    def compute_output_shape(self, batch_input_shape):
        return batch_input_shape

class plus3(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def call(self, X):
        return X + 3
    def compute_output_shape(self, batch_input_shape):
        return batch_input_shape
```

And the network is like below.

```py
def f1():
    return plus1()
def f2():
    return plus2()
def f3():
    return plus3()

def simple_model(input_num):
    input_layer = Input(input_num)
    rand = tf.random.uniform((1,), minval=0, maxval=3, dtype=tf.int32)
    r = tf.switch_case(rand[0], branch_fns={0: f1, 1: f2, 2: f3})
    res = r(input_layer)
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=res)
    return model

model = simple_model([1,])
```

Each time I run the code below, I get the same output, but I expected different ones.
Is there any way to implement this?

```py
model.predict([1])
>>> array([[4.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: What is your Tensorflow version? I tested your code with Tensorflow 2.4.1, and the script runs as expected.

Comment: The random layer is picked when the model is built with the `simple_model` function. After the model has been built its layers don't change anymore, that's why `model.predict([1])` returns always the same output. If you want `model.predict([1])` to return different outputs you need to rebuild the model every time. i.e. you need to run `model = simple_model([1, ]); model.predict([1])` instead of just  `model.predict([1])`.

Comment: I don't want to rebuild the model every time. So do you mean there isn't any way to have a model that choose different functionality/layer in each batch? @FlaviaGiammarino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the same problem I was facing and I found no solution. So I implemented distinct networks and then randomly selected from their output.

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with the same issue: I have a list of layers from which I need to select randomly on every iteration. `tf.switch_case()` gave me the same problem you describe.

For whatever reason, and I don't have enough background depth to tell you why (it's entirely plausible that my `tf.switch_case` implementation was buggy in an unrelated way), this code worked for me:

```
def random_layer(layers, image_tensor):
"""
Selects and executes a random layer chosen from a list
"""
to_use = tf.random.uniform(shape=[], maxval=len(layers), dtype=tf.int32)
out = image_tensor

for i, layer in enumerate(layers):
    # out is either image_tensor or the actual output, *but*
    # since we can't break this loop, when it matches it will become the actual output
    # and any further calls will return that value
    
    def _match():
        # tf.print("using {}".format(layer))
        return layer(out, training=True)
    out = tf.cond(to_use==i, _match, lambda: out)
    
return out
```

(Note that I'm using a local function just so I can verify the randomness.) And I pass in:

```
NOISE_LAYERS = [tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(stddev=.1),
               tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(stddev=.2),
               tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(stddev=.3),
               tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(stddev=.4)]
```

(This is part of dataset preparation in which I want images to contain varying amounts of noise.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you please show how to apply your solution to the OP's situation given their code? E.g, replace the `tf.switch_case(...)` statement in their code with something that would work (or make more changes, if necessary). Currently, it's hard to transfer your answer's idea to their situation